# charts using php

Tags: php, json, charts

i need to make charts (pie and bar) and working with php data.
the data is JSON encoded.

what are the best ways to generate charts. i am right now looking at Google Chart api. is there anything better (read: easier) than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google charts is nice, these are also excellent:

- amcharts (amcharts.com)
- open flash charts is one (http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/)
- xml/swf charts (http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/)
- amcharts and xml/swf charts both have free versions.

Answer (score 3):

pChart ( http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) is a also pretty popular choice.

I've used it in the past with satisfaction.

If I have to find a new charting library/API I'd probably go with the Google Chart API, though.

Comment: We use pChart for a project and I'm quite happy with it.  It's definitely more powerful and flexible than the Google Chart API. It's more complex though, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The PEAR Image_Graph package is a very powerful tool to create graphs.

Check out the samples here http://pear.veggerby.dk/samples/.

Answer (score 1):

**Google Fusion** is kind of new and does graphical representation of data. 
http://tables.googlelabs.com/Home

http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/

http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/12/google-fusion-tables-api.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery,
[JQuery Google Charting](http://keith-wood.name/gChart.html) makes using Google Charts API very easy.
Also, [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is very nice tool for plotting x/y charts, it does not provides pie charts, and lacks the concept of categories/datasets, but otherwise the most impressive.