# any good class for generating graphs and pie charts

Tags: php, jquery, css, graphics, charts

I'm working on a project which includes generating pie and bar graph charts on the fly with user inputs.

Can anyone suggest me some good libraries to do that?

It can be any like jquery, css, php class or anything **free**..

And i'm going to use it mainly **offline**. 
Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graphs/Charts in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395541/graphs-charts-in-php), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110839/best-graph-and-diagram-toolset-for-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147/pie-chart-drawing-in-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935330/php-chart-library-solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528263/what-is-the-best-open-source-php-charting-solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156252/free-chart-libraries-for-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038405/charts-using-php search SO with: [php] graph or chart

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this one. best ever -> http://jpgraph.net/

Answer (score 1):

i have used flot: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Answer (score 1):

Just saw: http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/

Looks pretty cool although I haven't actually done any development with it yet.